# newlfm date annoyance

Tags: newlfm

I have been using newlfm a part of TeXLive since 2007 for my official correspondence. I noticed that newlfm broke backward compatibility since TeXLive 2009. I read documentation (which is very long) several times over arguably not too carefully but I have never found a solution for the following annoying problem with the date. This is what I am talking about.[image]

Date should be aligned with the first letter of my first name "Predrag". This is the source code

```
\documentclass[12pt,stdletter,sigleft]{newlfm}
\usepackage{charter}

\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000

\newsavebox{\Luiuc}
\sbox{\Luiuc}{%
        \parbox[b]{1.75in}{%
                \vspace{0.5in}%
                \includegraphics[scale=1.0,ext=.eps]
                {figures/UILogoLG3L}%
        }%
}%
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}

\newlfmP{headermarginskip=20pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{dateskipafter=20pt}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}
\PhrPhone{Phone}
\PhrEmail{Email}

\lthUiuc

\namefrom{Predrag Puno\v{s}evac}
\addrfrom{%
        Predrag Puno\v{s}evac\\
        Science Laboratory\\
        Some University\\
        Urbana, IL 61801
}
\phonefrom{000-000-0000}
\emailfrom{xxx@hotmail.edu}

\addrto{%
Faculty Search Committee\\
Department of Science\\
Some University\\
Somewhere, SC 29634-0974}

\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}
\closeline{Sincerely,}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

I am writing to apply for the position of bla bla

Thank you for your consideration.  I look forward to
hearing from you.

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

I have avoided putting date on my letters due to the above behavior for several years. However, I decided that if I can not fix the above package I will switch either to plain TeX or ConTeXt for letters at least. By the way the more I play with ConTeXt the more I like it. I can not wait for Mark IV to mature little bit more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps not the best option, but you can use the `dateno` class option

```
\documentclass[12pt,stdletter,sigleft,dateno]{newlfm}
```

to avoid automatically typesetting the date and then add `\today` in `\addfrom`, to inherit its alignment

```
\addrfrom{%
        \today\\
        Predrag Puno\v{s}evac\\
        Science Laboratory\\
        Some University\\
        Urbana, IL 61801
}
```

Here's a complete example using portions of your example code (I suppresses all commands using the image since I don't have the actual image file):

```
\documentclass[12pt,stdletter,sigleft,dateno]{newlfm}
\usepackage{charter}

\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000

\newlfmP{headermarginskip=20pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{dateskipafter=20pt}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}
\PhrPhone{Phone}
\PhrEmail{Email}

\namefrom{Predrag Puno\v{s}evac}
\addrfrom{%
        \today\\
        Predrag Puno\v{s}evac\\
        Science Laboratory\\
        Some University\\
        Urbana, IL 61801
}
\phonefrom{000-000-0000}
\emailfrom{xxx@hotmail.edu}

\addrto{%
Faculty Search Committee\\
Department of Science\\
Some University\\
Somewhere, SC 29634-0974}

\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}
\closeline{Sincerely,}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

I am writing to apply for the position of bla bla

Thank you for your consideration.  I look forward to
hearing from you.

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another dirty hack is to use `\dateset` and then `\parbox` to manually align the date. That way you do not need to amend your address, which is useful if you use a letter database, *letrinfo.tex*, potentially containing many addresses. However, the drawback is alignment will have to be done manually every time for new addresses. Just add the line:

```
\dateset{\parbox{width}{\today}}
```

Where you need to adjust `width` so that the date aligns with the text of the address. In your document, on my machine, it was approximately 1.8 inches:

```
\documentclass[12pt,stdletter,sigleft]{newlfm}
\usepackage{charter}

\newlfmP{headermarginskip=20pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{dateskipafter=20pt}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}
\PhrPhone{Phone}
\PhrEmail{Email}


% ***** Manually adjust the position of the date. *****
\dateset{\parbox{1.8in}{\today}}


\namefrom{Predrag Puno\v{s}evac}
\addrfrom{%
    Predrag Puno\v{s}evac\\
    Science Laboratory\\
    Some University\\
    Urbana, IL 61801
}
\phonefrom{000-000-0000}
\emailfrom{xxx@hotmail.edu}

\addrto{%
Faculty Search Committee\\
Department of Science\\
Some University\\
Somewhere, SC 29634-0974}

\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}
\closeline{Sincerely,}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

I am writing to apply for the position of bla bla

Thank you for your consideration.  I look forward to
hearing from you.

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```